# Implementing Adwords conversion tracking with js/ajax based form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-ads-api

I am trying to figure out how to implement adwords conversion tracking in this web template that we purchased. I am not very familiar with javascript or ajax but here is how I believe it works:  When someone hits the submit button, a file (forms.js) processes whether the form was filled out correctly.  If it was filled out correctly, the .js file sends the form information to a mailhandler.php file (which notifies us via email of the form submission) as well as sends something back to the site telling it to display the successful submission message (which is in a hidden  tag).  So there is no actual thank-you page on which to include any conversion tracking code.

I just started using Google's Tag Manager so I am sure there is a way to utilize this to trigger the conversion code upon a successful form submission, I just cannot figure it out myself.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!!

The contact form is here:  http://www.unitedsupportllc.com/#!/page_mail

And the forms.js code is here:

```
//forms
;(function($){
$.fn.forms=function(o){
    return this.each(function(){
        var th=$(this)
            ,_=th.data('forms')||{
                errorCl:'error',
                emptyCl:'empty',
                invalidCl:'invalid',
                notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                successCl:'success',
                successShow:'4000',
                mailHandlerURL:'bat/MailHandler.php',
                ownerEmail:'myemail@address.com',
                stripHTML:true,
                smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                targets:'input,textarea',
                controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                validate:true,
                rx:{
                    ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-        Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                    ".state":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-   Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                    ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.  [\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                    ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                    ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                    ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                },
                preFu:function(){
                    _.labels.each(function(){
                        var label=$(this),
                            inp=$(_.targets,this),
                            defVal=inp.val(),
                            trueVal=(function(){
                                        var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                        return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                    })()
                        trueVal!=defVal
                            &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                        label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                        inp
                            .bind('focus',function(){
                                inp.val()==defVal
                                    &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                            })
                            .bind('blur',function(){
                                _.validateFu(label)
                                if(_.isEmpty(label))
                                    inp.val(defVal)
                                    ,_.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))                                          
                            })
                            .bind('keyup',function(){
                                label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                    &&_.validateFu(label)
                            })
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                    })
                    _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                },
                isRequired:function(el){                            
                    return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                },
                isValid:function(el){                           
                    var ret=true
                    $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                        if(el.is(k))
                            ret=d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())                                      
                    })
                    return ret                          
                },
                isEmpty:function(el){
                    var tmp
                    return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                },
                validateFu:function(el){                            
                    el.each(function(){
                        var th=$(this)
                            ,req=_.isRequired(th)
                            ,empty=_.isEmpty(th)
                            ,valid=_.isValid(th)                                

                        if(empty&&req)
                            _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                        else
                            _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                        if(!empty)
                            if(valid)
                                _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                            else
                                _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))                             
                    })
                },
                getValFromLabel:function(label){
                    var val=$('input,textarea',label).val()
                        ,defVal=label.data('defVal')                                
                    return label.length?val==defVal?'nope':val:'nope'
                }
                ,submitFu:function(){
                    _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
                    if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                            data&colon;{
                                name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                                email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                                phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                                fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
                                state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                                message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                                owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                            },
                            success: function(){
                                _.showFu()
                            }
                        })          
                },
                showFu:function(){
                    _.success.slideDown(function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            _.success.slideUp()
                            _.form.trigger('reset')
                        },_.successShow)
                    })
                },
                controlsFu:function(){
                    $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                        var th=$(this)
                        th
                            .bind('click',function(){
                                _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                return false
                            })
                    })
                },
                showErrorFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                },
                hideErrorFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                },
                showEmptyFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                    _.hideErrorFu(label)
                },
                hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                },
                init:function(){
                    _.form=_.me                     
                    _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                    _.preFu()

                    _.controlsFu()

                    _.form
                        .bind('submit',function(){
                            if(_.validate)
                                _.submitFu()
                            else
                                _.form[0].submit()
                            return false
                        })
                        .bind('reset',function(){
                            _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                            _.labels.each(function(){
                                var th=$(this)
                                _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                            })
                        })
                    _.form.trigger('reset')
                }
            }
        _.me||_.init(_.me=th.data({forms:_}))
        typeof o=='object'
            &&$.extend(_,o)
    })
}
})(jQuery)
$(window).load(function(){
$('#form1').forms({
    ownerEmail:'#'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (or least error-prone) way would probably be to use GTM's [dataLayer](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#datalayer) to push an event upon form submission:

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'form_submisssion'});
```

and then inside Google Tag Manager:

1. define a new ***rule*** catching the above event
2. create a new `Adwords Conversion Tracking` ***tag*** that fires when the rule matches

Comment: Dorian!  Thank you for your response.  I actually was on that exact route just recently.  I created the tag in GTM and have been trying to insert the code here or there waiting for a successful conversion but I have not figured it out yet.  Any ideas on where I could place that code to fire it properly?  Ideally, it would only fire upon a successful form submission...

Comment: I find the JS somewhat hard to parse, but a quick and dirty way would be to put the event call inside the `success` callback of the `jQuery.ajax()` call.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, Dorian.  I have tried inserting the line in what I think is the right spot but it doesn't seem to work.  I inserted it here: 
`success: function(){
                                _.showFu()
                            }` under the `_.showFU()`.  I even tried putting the `_.` before it (??) but wasn't able to get it to register.  Am I even in the ballpark here?